# switching between php and html in sublime while working in a file

Tags: php, html, sublimetext

hi every body here is my first question in stackoverflow :)
I'm new to php and sublime text. my question is: is there any way to switch between php and html in sublime text while you'r working in a file consists of both php and html?
what I mean is switching syntax highlighting, code snippets and etc.
for example consider this code:

```
<?php
  echo <<<_HTML
    <!--html code comes here
    -->
  _HTML;
?>
```

I know I can change view>syntax, however other things stay on php, fore example while i'm on html part i can not close tags by "alt+." and "ctrl+/" insert "//" instead of

```
<!-- -->
```

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest would be to actually get out of PHP and into HTML by closing the php tag:

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) 
    { 
?>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p> <!--html comment-->
<?php 
    } //this is php comment
?>
```

[image: Example of sublime highlighting both php and html]

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say - as well as giving the right highlighting it will usually make the code a lot more readable too :)

Comment: thanks dave ... yess it works!
it seems there is no way to change snippet behavior inside a block! so i should close the php tag first.